# Exporting to .csv from python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am quite new to this and cant seem to get this to export properly.

```py
# select document
with open('scrape1.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

# create/name csv
with open('speechengine_report.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['computer', 'usagedata']) 

# tell bs4 to only look at x tags with a class of y
for licensedata in soup.find_all('div', class_='licensedata'):

    # scrape pc id
    computer = licensedata.p.b.text
    print(computer)

    # scrape usage stats for each id
    for usagedata in licensedata.find_all('td'):

        # minutes = usagedata.table.tbody
        print(usagedata.text)

    # blank line
    print()

    # writer.writerow([computer, usagedata])

    
csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest of the code wherein you want to write data to your csv file should be within the **with** block. Also, you don't need csv_file.close() since with handles that for you. Try the below code. Read [file handling in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

```
with open('scrape1.html') as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')

# create/name csv
with open('speechengine_report.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['computer', 'usagedata']) 
    # tell bs4 to only look at x tags with a class of y
    for licensedata in soup.find_all('div', class_='licensedata'):

        # scrape pc id
        computer = licensedata.p.b.text
        print(computer)

        # scrape usage stats for each id
        for usagedata in licensedata.find_all('td'):

        # minutes = usagedata.table.tbody
            print(usagedata.text)

        # blank line
        print()

        # writer.writerow([computer, usagedata])
```